# How to search in eclipse methods called?

Tags: android, search

How to search within eclipse or MotoDev IDE which methods are being called and by which file? i.e. I have a method called Validate, but not sure how to search where it is called from which class or file that calls it?

Comment: Its simple select method and press F3

Comment: @ChiragRaval F3 will take you to the implementation or declaration of the method.

Comment: @Shahzeb Read Question what he asks ? where it is called from which class or file.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse:

Left click to highlight method or select it in outline.

After selection:

Right click on it -> References

or

Search -> References

and pick a range.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click a method name in the outline view or java source and choose "Open Call Hierarchy", which will display the complete call chain.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on method and click on references, (select the scope ie. workspace,project or hierarchy).